# Spring SpEL: how to write ternary operation in XML config?

Tags: spring, spring-el

In my Spring XML config, I need to set a value to a specific property value depending on the value of another property.

I need something like this:

```
<bean id="myid" class="myclass">
   <property name="myprop"
            value="#{${property_a} == 'test-a' ? ${property_b} : 'anothervalue'}"
   />
```

I want `myprop` to be set the value of `property_b` if `property_a` is equal to "test-a", otherwise `myprop` must be set to "anothervalue".

`property_a` and `property_b` are both defined in my `config.properties` file.

Is it possible to write such a statement in XML SpEL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<property name="myprop"
        value="#{'${property_a}' == 'test-a' ? '${property_b}' : 'anothervalue' }" />
```

You have to ensure that the result of properties placeholder resolution is still `literal`. So, that's why we must wrap `${...}` to `''`.

Comment: hi @Artem, can u pls have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64321418/spring-spel-in-xml-org-springframework-expression-parseexception-no-ending-suff