# Spring SpEL in XML org.springframework.expression.ParseException: No ending suffix '}' for expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have the below `applicationContext-security.xml` in which I am passing a list of filters based on some condition using SpEL but spring is not able to parse the expression due to comma.

```
    <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**"
                          filters="#{ '${portal.okta.login.enabled}' ? 'httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter' : 'httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter' }" />
    </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Above if you see  `: 'httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter'`, this is the one creating problems. If I remove comma and keep only single filter, spring parses it fine.

The value of the above if-else is consumed as a `List<Filter>`.
How should I go about it ? `portal.okta.login.enabled` is just a property that takes either true or false.

Comment: Can you post the whole error?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> Lists can be expressed directly in an expression using {} notation.

So this should do it:

```
'{httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter}'
```

See 8.5.3 here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: I added them as you said but still I get same error. `filters="#{ '${portal.okta.login.enabled}' ? 'httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter' : '{httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter}' }" />`